# KL divergence between noisy strings with small hamming distance

Tags: information-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be strings of length $n$ from a vocabulary of $m$ characters.  Suppose that the hamming distance between $x$ and $y$ is $d$, and that $d << n$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be noisy versions of $x$ and $y$, respectively, corrupted in the following way: each character is independently, with probability $p$, replaced with a character selected uniformly at random from $[m]$.

I computed the KL divergence between $X$ and $Y$ to be
$$ D(X||Y)  =  d \log \left( \frac{m}{p} - m + 1 \right) \left( 1 - p \right) $$

To my surprise, this quantity does not depend on the string length $n$.  I would have expected that $D(X||Y) \to 0$ if $d$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$.

Do you think I made a mistake in my computation, or is my result correct?

If the result is correct, is there any other information theoretic distance between probability distributions which *would* tend to zero as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a comment that got too long.

---

No, any useful notion of statistical distance will depend on $d$ but not $n$. Note that due to your noise model, the tuples $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i \in [1:n]}$ are mutually independent. Further, for the indices $i$ where $x_i = y_i,$ the distributions of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are the same. Ergo, these coordinates would simply be integrated out and not affect any distance. So, for instance, you have $$ D(P_X \|P_Y) = \sum_i D(P_{X_i} \| P_{Y_i}) = \sum_{i: x_i \neq y_i} D(P_{X_i}\|P_{Y_i})\\ = d D\left( (1-p)\mathbf{1}\{a = 0\} + \frac{p}{m} \| (1-p)\mathbf{1}\{a = 1\} + \frac{p}{m}\right),$$

which evaluates to your claim. The final equality again exploits symmetry of the distributions.

What *will* go to zero is normalised KL divergence $\frac{1}{n} D(P_X \|P_Y)$ (and indeed, any divergence appropriately normalised). The following statistical interpretation may help with intuition.

Recall that $D(P\|Q)$ controls the risk of a hypothesis test between $P$ and $Q$ for a tester that knows $P$ and $Q$. Your first result - that $D$ does not go to zero - is saying that if you let the tester look at the whole vector, then it will be able to exploit the $d$ differences to do hypothesis testing - this makes sense, the difference is constant and just because you have a longer string doesn't mean the tester is weaker - it knows where to look and just looks there. However, if the tester is only allowed to look at one *random* coordinate, then with high probability it will fail for long vectors. Note that effective KL divergence for this setting is $\frac{D}{n} = O(d/n)$.